# SEM: Acceptable to report standardized factor loadings that is exactly 1.00 (not above)?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, reporting, amos

I have a situation where an indicator pathway has a factor loading that is exactly 1.00 (in the AMOS output the estimate is .998).

The model converges, is positively defined and has a decent model fit (χ2 382.864, df: 99, CFI: .935, TLI: .911, RMSEA: .059).

Overall, there are five factors in the model, which are all theoretically based. The factor that has one indicator pathway with a factor loading of 1.00 has in total three manifest variables that are all theory driven. The factor loadings of the other two manifest variables are .90 and .76.

I would appreciate if you could give me some advice in regards to reporting a standardized factor loading that is 1.00?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first sentence is contradictory $0.998 \ne 1.00$

Comment: What else would you report? You report the result you have.